# sql cross reference table

Tags: sql, database

I amy trying to build a statistics table for marketing issues for specific site :

currently I planning to build table like this

```
Source_IP    source_city    Destination_IP   destination_city 
127.0.0.1       NY           242.212.12.1         Paris
242.212.12.1   Paris           127.0.0.1           NY
```

I want to prevent case like the above I.E the combination of (Source_ip , source_city) and (Destination_IP destination_city) should only be one record and not 2 how can i prevent this on sql?

Comment: First thing I would recommend is converting the IP addresses to integer values.   You'll save validation headaches if you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your DBMS allows function based indexes, the following would do the trick:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_no_dupes 
    ON your_table (least(source_ip, destination_ip), greatest(source_ip, destination_ip));
```

The use of `least` and `greatest` will always index the tuples in the "same order", so it doesn't matter which value is in which column.

If your DBMS does not support `least` or `greatest` you will need to replace this with a `CASE` construct.

Answer (score 0):

normalize your table ...

take one table for locations containing a location ID, the ip, and the city name

and have a 2nd table where you can put <strike>pairs of location ids</strike> a location id and a pair id ...

example:

table 1:

```
Location
    ID   IP             City   
    1    127.0.0.1      Ny   
    2    242.212.12.1   Paris
```

table 2:

```
Pairs
    ID    Location   
    1     1   
    1     2
```

Comment: That might be a better design but it still wouldn't solve the problem of avoiding A B and B A pairs.

Comment: @SteveWellens ... i had a poor choice of words ... myabe it's clear now

Answer (score 0):

<del>For MS SQL Server you could implement a check constraint</del>

My first idea was, well, a first idea.  So, there are better suggestions here, but another possibility, though probably not a great one, is to implement a trigger on insert or update to first search the table to make sure that those items don't exist elsewhere.  If none is found, then the trigger allows the action, otherwise, it rolls back.  Like I said, not great, but a possibility.

Comment: How can you define a check constraint that checks multiple rows?

Comment: A check constraint with source IP < destination IP would "work" (but at the expense of complicating the insertion code)